# Need recommendation for c++ game server ,on whitch data structures to use for a player, monster objects, to gain performence benefit

Tags: c++, data-structures

Currently I am using vector of classes data structure for objects, but I believe that is not very efficient for performance issue. I commonly perform searches in vector for particular objects so it kind-of gets slow, when there are a lot of objects.

Comment: For starters, what *kind* of game is it?  FPS, MMO, etc.?  This will likely dictate what kinds of operations you will perform on the data, which will undoubtedly drive your data structure selection criteria...

Comment: @hatboyzero That sounds like a rather odd assessment to me.

Comment: Have you determined that there is a performance issue, and that it has something to do with searching your vectors?  (Saying it "kind-of gets slow" suggests a performance problem, but not where it is; there's lots of things that could get slow with lots of objects.)

Comment: How do you "perform searches"?  For object types?  Do they have an identifier that could be used (to index the `vector`) giving you constant-time performance?

Comment: It may be the case that you're searching too much, and no data structure will help against that. It's impossible to say anything concrete about this without more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `vector` is ordered binary searches with [upper_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) and [lower_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) are going to perform very good. If your vector is not ordered and objects are inserted often (which would imply reordering it or copying a lot of elements to preserve the order) a [map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) or [unordered_map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) is a very good search structure.

However, all those are general purpose solutions and there might be more efficient solutions depending on your specific use case (insert often, remove often, size critical).

But you should definitely profile your application first to make sure you are not optimizing the wrong part.

Comment: If using binary search, remember the `binary_search` algorithm in the C++ standard library.  Binary search is notoriously hard to get right, so you're almost certainly better off using the library version.

Comment: @DavidThornley At the same time, `std::binary_search` only checks for existence of a value and gives no reference to it. That's why `lower_bound` is often more useful.

Comment: Forgot that, but in any case it's much better to use a library binary search than writing your own in almost all cases.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at something like `std::map`.  If your objects have, say, IDs, then you can look up objects using that ID rather than having to iterate through a vector each time you want to do look for something.

There's LOTS more to all of this than this simplistic answer, but it should get you started.